# Autohyphenation of compound Russian words

Tags: xetex, languages, hyphenation, polyglossia

The title says it all... how?

There are a lot of compound Russian words that have a hyphen and they need to be hyphenated just like any other word.

Polyglossia can do this for German with `"-` and `"=` and whatnot, but nothing like that for Russian.

A command to insert a non-hyphenation-suppressing-hyphen would be nice, a command to enable hyphenation in all such words by default would be super helpful.

Comment: Does `\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}` not give you access to `"=` etc.?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You can use `babel` instead of `polyglossia`. The most recent version of `babel` provides "= and works with all engines including xetex and luatex.

Comment: @brian-ammon: Tried that, no luck. `[babelshorthands=true]{german}` does work, just like the manual says, but `{russian}` does not.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov: Yeah, `babel` can do it, but I have other problems with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel shorthands work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Old Standard}

\begin{document}
\parbox{3pt}{
\hspace{0pt}штаб"-квартиры

\bigskip

\hspace{0pt}Восточно"-Европейской
}
\end{document}
```

The `\hspace{0pt}` is used to overcome the usual problem that the first word in a paragraph would not be hyphenated. The `\parbox` is to force XeLaTeX to hyphenate whenever possible.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I was using `babelshorthands` incorrectly (`option` is not the same as `option=true`, silly me). However `"-` doesn't seem to work as intended. It produces no hyphen when word fits on the line (`ВосточноЕвропейской`). `-""` seems to do the right things however.

Comment: There was a bug with `"-` until last year, which would cause the behaviour you’re observing.  It’s fixed in TeX Live 2012 (with Polyglossia version 1.2.1).

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer: perhaps, you need `"=` rather than `"-`.

Comment: @Igor: I don’t need anything myself, I am only reporting a bug that has been fixed in the mean time.  In that particular case, updating may help the original poster.